# Confusion about the integral $\sin 2x$

Tags: integration

If $$I=\int\sin 2x\, \mathrm{d}x$$
since $$(\sin^2x)'=2\cos x\sin x=\sin 2x$$ then $$I=\sin^2x+C$$

However using substitution
$$I=\int \frac{\sin2x}{-2\sin 2x}\,\mathrm{d}u,~~~~\textrm{s.t}~~~ u=\cos2x$$
giving $$I=-\frac{1}{2}\int\,\mathrm{d}u=-\frac{1}{2}\cos2x+C=\sin^2x-\frac{1}{2}+C$$

I have checked on WolframAlpha and the second answer is correct. My question is why is the first answer wrong?
I have checked the derivative is correct and I am sure $f'=g\Longleftrightarrow f+C=\int g$ is true also.

I have looked online but have found nothing other than the second answer.

Comment: Both answers are correct.

Answer (score 3):

Both answers are correct. As you know when you integrate you always need to add a constant. In your two answers the constants are expressed different. In the first you have labelled it $C$ and the second you have labelled it $C-\frac{1}{2}$.

In otherwords your two constants different by a factor of $\frac12$.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct as $$C+\sin^2x=C+1-\cos^2x=K-\cos^2x$$
where $K=C+1$

as $$\cos2x=2\cos^2x-1=1-2\sin^2x$$

Answer (score 1):

The difference between both results is *a constant*: they both are correct since indefinite integral is determined **only up to a constant**, so for example

$$\int x\;dx=\frac12x^2+C=\frac12x^2-567+K=\frac12x^2+1000+C_1\;,\;\;\text{etc.}$$